# How to check if a list of XY coordinate meet the safety distance to each others?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

My background is not CS so sorry for using improper term. But basically I want to check if a point on XY plane is "too close" to any other points, and do so with every points. In another words, if I draw a circle with radius R at every points, would any circle cross other circles on the plane.

I want to code this in Python, if that matters.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://efekarakus.github.io/fixed-radius-near-neighbor/) will help.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are solving has many well-known efficient algorithms.

The problem is to find closest pair of points in the plane.
If the closest pair have distance less than the safety distance, you already have a pair.
If not, no other pair can have a less distance, and hence all pairs are safe.

One efficient way to solve this problem is using [divide and conquer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points-using-divide-and-conquer-algorithm/). The algorithm is practical and easy to implement. It has run-time $O(n \log n)$ (check the notes at the end).

It might be an over-kill, but as efficient from the theoretical point of view, to build [Delaunay-Triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) over the set of points and compare each point to its neighbors in the triangulation, which is also achievable in $O(n \log n)$.

There are many libraries that offer a ready-to-use Delaunay-Triangulation (you can check CGAL-Boost library for C++), which makes it an easier way to implement that the previous method.

**ps.** Another very well-known approach, used in many different problems is line-sweep. There is also a line-sweep $O(n \log n)$ algorithm for Closest pair of points problem. (please check the [link](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/geometry/line-sweep-technique/tutorial/)).

Comment: "The problem is to find the closest distance in the plane" - no, it's not. The problem is showing there is no distance below the minimum safe distance.

Comment: I know, the two lines following that line explain why both problems are equivalent in this context

Comment: They are not, because if I take the first two points and they are close together, Op’s Question is answered. The problem you want to solve is generally much harder.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many points, say a million, you want to do something that is faster than comparing each point to each other point.

There is a simple method that is far from perfect but will give you a significant advantage:

You start by sorting all the points by their x-value. The way you describe it, you want the distance between any two points to be at least 2R. So you iterate through the points, and for each point with x-coordinate X, you only examine the following points in the sorted array as long as their x-coordinate is at most X + 2R.

You know you have checked previous points in the sorted array earlier, so they don't need to be checked again. As a result, instead of comparing a point with all other points, you only compare it with points in the stripe X to X+2R. That should reduce the number of points to compare a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spatial index, such as quadtree, kd-tree, R-tree, ... . Most implementations of spatial indexes provide a search method that returns all indexed points in a circle or rectangle.
Before inserting any point P, you can simply query/search the index whether there is already any point in the rectangle/circle around P, where the rectangle/circle encompasses the safety distance. Of course, if you use a rectangle, you have to manually check whether the returned points really violate the safety distance.

These searches are usually in the order of $O(log (n))$, so checking all points requires something like $O(n * log(n))$.